# DeprecationWarning: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, deprecation-warning

My code snippet is as follows:

```
data,l = make_moons(100000)
s = np.random.permutation(100000);
temp1 = data[s[0:200],:] # Random Sampling of 200 columns 
temp2 = cdist(data,temp1) # Pairwise distance between two sets of observations
C = np.exp(-temp2/sig)
W = C[s[0:200],:]
```

where make_moons is defined as:

```
from math import pi

def make_moons(n):
    """Create a 'two moons' dataset with n feature vectors, 
        and 2 features per vector."""

    assert n%2==0, 'n must be even'
    # create upper moon
    theta = np.linspace(-pi / 2, pi / 2, n/2)
    # create lower moon
    x = np.r_[np.sin(theta) - pi / 4, np.sin(theta)]
    y = np.r_[np.cos(theta), -np.cos(theta) + .5]
    data = np.c_[x, y]
    # Add some noise
    data = data + 0.03 * np.random.standard_normal(data.shape)

    # create labels
    labels = np.r_[np.ones((n//2, 1)), -np.ones((n//2, 1))]
    labels = labels.ravel().astype(np.int32)

    return data,labels
```

I want to get some insight into the captioned warning. As I see, the arrays are floating type but why are they interpreted (or need to be) as integer?

Comment: In the line `theta = np.linspace(-pi / 2, pi / 2, n/2)`, you're using `n/2` as the number of points. But (assuming you're not using Python 2) `n/2` is a float. Use `n//2` instead of `n/2`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Gotcha, thanks!